Vague Flow Error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER - An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
I've spent all day troubleshooting a flow error and I can't figure it out.
Issue:

On a custom object called Request, I manually updated the Stage field to "Approved Pending Agreement." This change triggers an after-save flow on that object, which is triggered by any edit on the object.
The error occurs on an "Update Request" action, which has "Use the IDs and all field values from a record or record collection" chosen. It's updating the triggering record.
The error is happening across record type and on every record I've tried. It started within the last few days and was working before that.

Troubleshooting

To troubleshoot, I updated the flow so it jumps directly to the Update Request action and no changes are made before that. The error still occurs, which means it's not a problem with the flow itself. Because the action is updating the triggering record as a whole without any manual mapping, I wonder if the error is due to re-saving some existing value on the record.
The Validation Rules related to the Stage field are not being triggered.
We use Rollup Helper and there is an exception for a related rollup. The exception says the related filters don't exist. I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the filters or rollup, so I deactivated it and tried to change the Stage to Approved Pending Agreement again. The error still occurred.
I ran a debug log with the finest granularity and didn't see a more specific error message.
There haven't been any changes to the Stage field or permissions.
I reviewed the other flows that have been edited recently and I don't see anything related to the Stage field or Approved Pending Agreement picklist value.
We don't have any custom code that could be causing problems.

Any other ideas about what might be going wrong?

Error: The flow tried to update these records: a0AVG000002FY3R2AW.
This error occurred: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this
record because the “Request- After Save” process failed. Give your
Salesforce admin these details. An unhandled fault has occurred in
this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please
contact your system administrator for more information.occurred while
processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more
information.. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API
Developer Guide.


Hi Rochelle!  I prefer to update only the specific fields you want and avoid the "use all field values", even though that requires more steps.  Have you tried assigning  a record variable with only the fields you want updated?

You shouldn't need debug at finest level to detect the root cause, if anything, this may obscure the issue due to overwhelming noise.   Some downstream automation that occurs when Update Request action is failing. Perhaps you have more than one RollupHelper involved, some other managed package, trigger, or other flow

@DavidCheng Hi David! I updated the flow so it manually assigns the changes. The error still occurred, but it happened further down the flow. So, it seems like making your suggested change made it possible for the flow to show me what was actually wrong. It was because a subflow variable had been deleted, so launching it failed. Thanks!
